# UWP UserControl Resources Binding to x:Bind

Tags: c#, uwp, xbind

In this xaml snippet I tried to specify the ViewModel and the Locator for the x DataType to change the bindings to x:Bind, but unfortunately that doesn't work here. Why can't I simply omit the specification of Source={StaticResource Locator} and address the whole thing via the x DataType, what am I doing wrong?

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="appointmentTemplate" >
        <Grid Background="White" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                    <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CalendarUCView.GridTappedCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Converter={StaticResource cellModelToEventsConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource appointmentCellListViewStyle}"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
                        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding CalendarUCView.SelectedAppointment, Source={StaticResource Locator}, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CalendarUCView.ItemTappedCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"/>
                    </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </ListView>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource cellModelToDayConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Margin="4"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I tryed:

```
     <DataTemplate x:Key="appointmentTemplate" 
     x:DataType="viewModel:CalendarUCViewModel" >
```

and also:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="appointmentTemplate" 
     x:DataType="locator:CalendarUCView" >
```

So usually I can do this:

```
    Command="{x:Bind GridTappedCommand}"
```

instead of that:

```
    Command="{Binding CalendarUCView.GridTappedCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
```

Or if I change the x:DataType to the View (x:DataType="local:CalendarUCView") and use in View:

```
     public CalendarUCViewModel Vm
     {
        get => (CalendarUCViewModel)DataContext;
     }
```

usually can do this:

```
    Command="{x:Bind Vm.GridTappedCommand}"
```

Comment: If you set the `x:DataType` attribute to `viewModel:CalendarUCViewModel`, you should be able to `x:Bind` to any property of `CalendarUCViewModel` only.

Comment: All propertys are from the VM, I think the direct Binding to the Converters are the Problem. I must find an way to do this with propertys from the VM because I find nothing about direct x:Bind to Converter. Thx for answer.

Comment: So what is the `Locator`? And what is the real problem? You can't use the x:Bind or something?

Comment: The Locator is a class where all ViewModels are getting registered in an IOC.Container to locate sending and recipient ViewModels from everywhere. Sorry you are right my real problem i didn't explain specifically. The commands are not triggered when setting x:Bind.

Comment: Is the issue only happen for command binding or does it happens to other kinds of bindings as well?